# Pause/Play functionality from one button?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to use one icon in the Windows Phone Application Bar to enable a user to tap it to play and pause background audio that I've inserted as a MediaElement in the XAML. This is my code:

```
 private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlayState.Playing == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause();
        }
        else if (PlayState.Paused == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
        }
```

It makes sense reading it through and does not throw up any errors when building, however when I tap it whilst testing on my device, the music does not pause and carries on playing (I've set AutoPlay = true to achieve this) Could someone tell me what I should do to enable one button to control play and pause functionality?

Also if I remove the "else if" and make the code into a simple "else" so it looks like this:

```
 private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlayState.Playing == BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState)
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Pause();

        }
        else
        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();

        }
    }
```

it pauses, but does not resume to play!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step implementation to achieve play/pause functionality

[click and get solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This is the one I attempted to follow, however the button simply toggles the audio to off instead of on AND off.

Answer (score 0):

"I've inserted as a MediaElement in the XAML."

If you are using a MediaElement, I think you are playing the audio in the foreground. Try closing out of your app after the audio starts. Does it keep playing? To pause and play a media element you can just use the play and pause methods on the media element.

```
nameOfMediaElement.Pause();
nameOfMediaElement.Play();
```

To use the event handlers that use the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState, you have to setup the initial audio playing back in the background. For this you need to start the audio playback via the BackgroundAudioPlayer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I had considered doing two separate buttons with a play/pause function implemented, which would incorporate the code you mentioned in your post, how would I set up the audio? I believe it would be "track" method but how would this be implemented? The button should act as a "toggle" for playing/pausing or muting/un-muting audio.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
if(mediaelement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
{
    mediaelement.Play(); 
}
else
{
    mediaelement.Pause();
}
```

Hope it works for you.